# ORM from Google

Tags: java, orm

Google provide many wonderful tools and APIs. However, I wonder if there is a database ORM (object-relational mapping) framework implemented by Google in Java? Or what ORM framework is used by googlers?

Comment: I don't think ( I might be wrong ) Google uses ORM at all. They use Bigtable for all their applications. They offer JPA in Google App Engine, but you can't use it out of it.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.html

Comment: Oh, I see. But as far as I know Facebook use MySQL to store key-value pairs. Google might have particular use cases to deal with RDBMS.

Comment: Although, I agree: dealing with ORM looks opposite to scalability due to impedance mismatch.

Comment: @NikitaZhiltsov: Facebook gave up Mysql looooong ago. They're using Hadoop and some super specialized home made storage solutions. With the risk of getting a throng of negative votes/comments, I think Mysql would never scale to Facebook's current (and future) storage needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[JStORM](http://www.urielkatz.com/archive/detail/introducing-jstorm/) is an ORM developed at Google.

Comment: Thanks. But I probably have to clarify the question: I'm looking for ORM for databases.

Comment: @Kikita looks like JStORM **is** for databases, but also for Javascript though

Comment: is there any ORM developed by Google for Android Sqlite

Comment: @LOG_TAG: I am not sure.  What has your search-fu showed?  I found http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml, but I don't think it is developed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

[Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) is technically [another] ORM from Google introduced in Google I/O 2017; of course not for JEE scenarios but for Android. I like its API, I hope it will find its way beyond Android.